# Best alternative for 'long term' storing model-view-controller data in Objective-C/ios

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, store

I am planning on creating my app in a '`Model-View-Controller`'(MVC)-style, and in the end, for me at least, this means that all data is stored in the controller-class. Let's say I have a class `Player`, and the player has several objects of class `Weapons` or `Equipment` or whatever. The initialization of `Controller*` stores the player(s), so if I can store/save only the `Controller`-object over time, even if the app or the device restarts, that would be nice. I did this in Java one, I put in `Serialization = 100L;`(or something like it) in the top of the file of every object that would be included when saving the `Controller`-object, and it worked perfectly. Is this possible in ios/cocoa-touch/objective-c?

I have read and used `Core Data` (not very much), but that is just a database-table, sql?, which would have me extract every piece of information of every object? 
For instance, if the object `Player*` has a member `NSString *name;`, I would have to save the actual string in Core Data, instead of saving the object of the player? Like, varchar.

If there is any way to store an entire custom object on the device for further use, I would very much like to know what it's called, and where I can read about it/tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on the NSCoding protocol. You can make your object complient to it, then serialized it and save it to a file. Later you can restore it to the same state by using a decoder. For sure some other posts that cover this topic on SO.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like what I had in mind, I just didn't know what to search for.

Comment: I have done exactly this with "past orders" in an ecommerce app and it works great!